# passing a list in between()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter() a dataframe using dplyr and I would like to filter based on a custom range specified by a list/ values in another data frame.

An example of what I am trying to do is follows. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
a<- data.frame(source=c(1,22,36,41,5))
d<- a$source

t<- 0.1
al<- a$source- t
ah<- a$source + t

b= data.frame(source= c(1:50))

#filtering based on a list ( this works)
c<- b %>% filter(source %in% d) 

#(filtering based on a fixed range, this works)
c<- b %>% filter(between(source,2,5)) 

#I am stuck here when I try to pass a series of values in between()
 c<- b %>% filter(between(source,al,ah))
```

Is there another way of doing this? or doing this with the existing code? Is there something I am missing in the dplyr package.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using `rowwise()` in dplyr:

```
b %>% rowwise() %>% filter(sum((source>al)*(source<ah))>0) %>% ungroup()
```

This returns:

```
source
   <int>
1      1
2      5
3     22
4     36
5     41
```

`sum((source>al)*(source<ah))` returns the number of intervals where a value falls. If it falls in one interval, it will return 1. If it falls in 2 (in case of overlapping intervals), it will return 2, etc..

---

You can also use the `findInterval` method. You can create one vector from al and ah:

```
v=c(rbind(sort(al),ah[order(al)]))
[1]  0.9  1.1  4.9  5.1 21.9 22.1 35.9 36.1 40.9 41.1
```

Then find out if your values fall in an odd or even interval:

```
b %>% filter(findInterval(source,v)%%2==1)
```

Note that this method only works if your intervals are non-overlapping.

Comment: Honestly, your previous suggestion to use `findInterval` worked better than rowwise().

Comment: The `rowwise()` method works even if intervals overlap which is not the case of the `findInterval` method. I've included them both.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: What didn't work for you with the `rowwise()` method?

Comment: It was my fault, I had overlooked a part while translating the code. It works just as well.

Comment: However, I seem to have fallen into a similar trap again. I am trying to assign labels to the newly filtered column and am unable to pass multiple values in `match` . 
If we assume `a` to have another column with labels in it. How can I assign them to the output of `rowwise`. 
Previously since I was doing exact matches `match` worked. Do you have any thoughts on that.
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. What do you use `match` for? What is its input and expected output? If it's a completely different question, you may want to post a new question.

Comment: So, it linked to this question..
if a was..
`a<- data.frame(source=c(1,22,36,41,5), name=c("stop", "halt", "go","think","talk"))
c<-b %>% filter(findInterval(source,v)%%2==1)

c$name<- c$name[match(b$source,a$source)] # makes a separate column with the names in it from a.`

Here `match` works only for exact matches from source in a to source in b. 
I cannot think of a way to modify this code to assign the associated in a label if b$source falls within an interval defined by a$source+-mt.

I have tried 
I hope that helps.

Comment: You don't need to use `match`. Just do `a %>% filter(findInterval(source,v)%%2==1)`. You will filter the lines of a that match the condition.

Comment: But b does not have labels in it. 
along with filtering b using the interval specified by a I want to print the labels. 
Its like grouping them with a string instead of having to use numbers in downstream application.
Does that make sense?
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, sorry. Is it `c$name=a[match(c$source,a$source),"name"]` you are looking for? Comments are not a good place for extended discussion.. You may want to start a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a separate question for it over here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945981/using-match-to-assign-labels-when-a-value-falls-in-an-interval

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `between` expects a single value for the boundary conditions.

You could try to do:

```
c<- b %>% filter(source > al & source < ah)
```

However, I find this a little weird because the `al` and `ah` will be recycled to match the size of `b$source`.

Comment: Thank you.I actually tried it and gives me the following warning and I do not know what to do with it.
Warning messages:
1: In c(112.98, 174.95, 112.98, 174.95, 112.98, 174.95, 112.98, 112.98,  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In c(112.98, 174.95, 112.98, 174.95, 112.98, 174.95, 112.98, 112.98,  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

I have no idea how this would affect the other elements in the output dataframe. Would you have any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

`between` expects a single value for the lower/upper bounds.  You could loop through the values like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(al)){

  print(b %>% filter(between(source,al[i],ah[i])))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not very comfortable with using for loops in R at the moment.