# Using match() to assign labels when a value falls in an interval

Tags: r, dplyr, match

I am trying to update my code to assign labels to values fall between a range specified by a column in a dataframe. I am using `match` which assigns labels only for exact matches between columns. How do you modify this to assign a label by matching with a range?
the sample code is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
a<- data.frame(source=c(1,25,41,36,45, 19), name=c("stop", "halt", "go","think","talk","sit"))

d<- a$source

t<- 0.2
al<- a$source- t
ah<- a$source + t

b= data.frame(source= c(1:50,1.1:50.1))
v=c(rbind(sort(al),ah[order(al)]))
v
c<-b %>% rowwise() %>% filter(sum((source>al)*(source<ah))>0) %>% ungroup() #thank to @lamia

c$name<-a$name[match(c$source,a$source)] # problem
c$name
```

As you can see using `match` only labels exact matches between the two sources. Is it possible to assign the label that "1" receives to "1.1" since it falls in the same interval.

Thank you.

Comment: Just apply something like `integer()` or `round()` on both sources. Something Like this:          `c$name<-a$name[match(integer(c$source),integer(a$source)]`

Comment: `round()` worked. I totally did not think about it. Was complicating it for no reason.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want a more general answer that will work with any range (not just integers) you can create an indicator with `cut` and match based on that.